# Why is this causing an error?

Tags: vba, excel

Why does this cause an error?

`Set rQueryCopy = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(5, 7))`

I have `rQueryCopy Dim As Range`.  I want rQueryCopy to equal cells `A5:G5` on Sheet1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) you need to use `Dim rQueryCopy As Range` instead `rQueryCopy Dim As Range`. 2) check please whether you really have sheet with name "Sheet1"

Comment: When you say "causing an error", it's **extremely helpful** if you also tell us what the error is; you have that information right in front of you, so there's absolutely no reason not to include it in your question. If you want help here, *be specific*, and provide the details that will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Also, sometimes you will have to include the Sheet reference in the Cells() function as well. So Set rQueryCopy = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5,1),Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5,7)). It may be easier to create another variable called ws. Dim ws as Worksheet. Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1"). Then replace all Sheets("Sheet1") with ws.

Comment: The error message is: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: When I try to run the macro while I'm on Sheet1 I don't get the error, but I do if I try it while on Sheet3.  I'll try creating the worksheet variable

Comment: The worksheet variable seemed to fix it.  I'll be sure to include error messages in future posts

Answer (score 1):

```
Set rQueryCopy = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 7))
```

the Cells part simply looks on activesheet, not on "sheet1", so you need to specify...
same goes with working with multiple workbooks....

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is they're not adjacent cells in a specific range. You're selecting specific individual cells.

```
Union(Cells(5, 1), Cells(5, 7)).Copy
'Do whatever you want from here, like paste
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

When you paste them they'll come out as two individual cells directly next to each other. If you want to paste them into specific once again non adjacent locations you'll need to just do it individually.

EDIT: Misread your question, I'll fix that now. Use this:

```
Dim rQueryCopy As Range
Set rQueryCopy = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:G5")
```